# Google Sheets Query - Multiple Select Statement If Condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Currently, I have a worksheet in Google Sheets that uses the formula:

`=query('Form Responses 1'!A2:AC,"Select A,B,D,L,M,N,O,P Where L is not null")`

This selects the columns *A,B,D,L,M,N,O,P Where L is not null* but if L is null, I want to select the *columns A,B,D,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC* instead.

So far, I've tried both of the following:

`=query('Form Responses 1'!A2:AC,"Select A,B,D,L,M,N,O,P Where L is not null" AND "Select A,B,D,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC Where Y is not null")`

`=query('Form Responses 1'!A2:AC,"Select A,B,D,L,M,N,O,P Where L is not null" OR "Select A,B,D,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC Where Y is not null")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

The following formula should produce the result you desire:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(L2:L),{A2:A,B2:B,D2:D,Y2:Y,Z2:Z,AA2:AA,AB2:AB,AC2:AC},{A2:A,B2:B,D2:D,L2:L,M2:M,N2:N,O2:O,P2:P}))
```

### Explanation

First, the `=ISBLANK` function is used to check whether the value of column L is empty or not. This creates an array of boolean values which are fed into the `=IF` function. Depending on the result of `=ISBLANK` one of two possible sets of columns are selected.

Everything is contained within `=ARRAYFORMULA` so that it functions properly across many rows.

Functions used:

- [=ISBLANK](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290?hl=en)
- [=IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)
- [=ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)